# Help getting this flight controller to work with this receiever

Tags: quadcopters, flight-controller, receiver, radio-frequency

I am working on building a drone. I have the [DJI NAZA M LITE](https://www.dji.com/naza-m-lite) flight controller, and [this receiver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P8N2SCB). The pinout for the battery and ESCS is pretty clear, but I'm not sure how I should go about connecting the RC reciever to the flight controller.

It seems based on the user manual that I should connect the rx/tx to the signal of X2, 5V on the reciever to 5V of X2, and gnd on the reciever to gnd of X2. However, I don't want to cut wires, solder, and connect things before figuring out the right way to do it, cause I don't want to do something where I cant go back.

Could someone let me know if this is the right way to connect it, or if I need to do something else?

Comment: I don't know that flight controller, but the leads look like ordinary servo plugs, which you can buy for around $1 on ebay, so don't worry about cutting those. Also, it says it supports S-Bus and PPM, but doesn't mention Spektrum's srxl2 protocol - it may not work (although you might be able to find updated firmware that does).

Comment: @RobinBennett Oh okay, thanks. So I guess I should try and see if the spektrum reciever I have works with the flight controller, by connecting the reciever wires to X2 on the flight controller, and if it doesn't then I should get an SBUS reciever instead?

Comment: You could try looking in the firmware setup for the flight controller, and see if it has an option for reading SRXL2 - also check for firmware updates. If you have to change receiver, you'll probably have to change transmitter too. This might help https://oscarliang.com/rc-protocols/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unlikely that the Naza M lite supports SRXL2, *especially* out of the box since SRXL is many years newer than the Naza line of flight controllers.

That being said:

- "+" goes to 5v (or 3.3, but I think spektrum has done away with 3v3 hardware)
- "-" goes to ground
- "S" goes to the "rx" line of a UART. RX1 or RX2 or RX3 or whatever. Note this means the TX line of the same uart should not have any peripherals
- "NC" means "no connect". Leave this open - it's probably for future support since I see all the SRXL receivers have that pin

"DJI Naza SRXL2" doesn't give me many results, but I didn't dig too much. You *might* get lucky if you can run it in legacy mode, and set the naza up for legacy spektrum satellite, but even that is unlikely.

Can you provide more details on why you chose this receiver and flight controller combo? This is a cinematic/slow flying flight controller and a race/high performance receiver

Comment: TBH I sorta chose that flight controller because I had experience with DJI but it was pretty outdated and very problematic. I recently redesigned the drone with a pixhawk based flight controller and it was so much better in every way (performance, documentation, logging, resources)